# Shows error when executing test case using keyword driven approach in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot framework automation testing.I wrote script and library for simple Quiz application using Python and follows keyword driven approach for test cases.
my script is:

```
class Quiz(object):
OPTIONS = 'ab'
count = 0

def __init__(self):
    self._score = 0
    Quiz.count+=1
def score(self, str1):
    if str1 not in self.OPTIONS:
        raise QuizError("Invalid button '%s'." % str1)
    if str1 == 'a' and Quiz.count == 1:
        self._score +=1 
    elif str1 == 'a' and Quiz.count == 2:
        self._score +=1
    elif str1 == 'a' and Quiz.count == 3:
        self._score +=1
    return self._score  


class QuizError(Exception):
pass
```

library file:

```
from quiz import Quiz, QuizError
class QuizLibrary(object):


def __init__(self):
    self._calc = Quiz()
    self._result = 0

def option(self, answer):        
    self._result = self._calc.score(answer)


def result(self, expected):

    if self._result != expected:
        raise AssertionError('%s != %s' % (self._result, expected))
```

keyword_driven.txt:

```
*** Settings ***

Library quizlibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***

Quiz Answer

    option    a

    option    b

    option    a

    result    2
```

It shows the following error:

```
Quiz Answer                                                                FAIL |
No keyword with name 'option' found.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testcase :: Example test cases using the keyword-driven testing approach.       | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

could anyone help me to solve this?

Please let me know how to create user keywords in keyword driven approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem with the name of the Python module used for your keyword library.

- if the name of your module is QuizLibrary.py, then change the case in the Library import in your test:

> Library  QuizLibrary.py

- if the name of your module is quizlibrary.py, then align the name of the class with this:

> class quizlibrary(object):

And also, don't forget to have at least 2 spaces between "Library" and the name of the library.

Comment: No problem with the name of module.But it always shows "keyword not Found".could you tell me why this error is shown?

Comment: I copied your code locally (with the fix I suggested) and could make it work properly... So if you still have the "keyword not found" it means the libary is not properly loaded. In the log, don't you have any error message about the loading of the lib?

Comment: ya..problem is resolved with your suggestion.Thanks for the response